# Why was my question put on hold?

Tags: support

I asked a question about setting up Drupal, and posted as much information as possible. This included adding error messages and information about my system (php version, sql, etc.). I also made an attempt to log out error information in order to diagnose the issue.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197400/500-server-error

It seems that the response to this has been to close the question on the basis that it was related to programming. Was this because I outlined *how* I went about trying to log out the information, or perhaps because I provided too much system information (one too many `php`'s in the body of the question?)

> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on-
>   and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by
>   reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this
>   specific reason:
>
> "Questions on programming, PHP, SQL, etc. that do not relate directly
>   to Drupal are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow."

Did I do myself a disservice by providing detailed information about the system and log settings? If that is the case, how can I expect to use this site to help me set up Drupal? I'm kind of at a loss at this point on how to seek help to get Drupal running...

Comment: I asked a question about Drupal 8 too, asking why authorize.php would think I am not logged in, and at the end I closed it because every time I installed Drupal 8 with the Softaculous installer, the behavior changed. I understand well the feeling of not being able to install Drupal 8. Asking on Drupal Answers was my first thought after various temptatives to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

That closing question is normally used for the *not relate directly to Drupal*. We should actually extend that closing reason to explicitly say that questions about server should be asked on the specific Stack Exchange there is for that.

I am not saying your question is off-topic for us. I see why it was closed, and I think it's quite difficult to say it's Drupal-specific or not. It should not be Drupal-specific if the same behavior could be reproduced with other software, including Symfony; that is a though call, IMO, in this case. Probably, it depends from something the installer is trying to do, even if I don't understand why the installer that comes with cPanel is able to install Drupal 8 without errors, or with minimal problems.

To make it clear, not all the problems you have while installing or using Drupal make Drupal-specific questions. For example, a question asking how to install the APC extension required by a module would not be a Drupal-related question, even if the OP would say "but I am asking here because it was a module asking me to install that extension."